# Error "Setting an array element with a sequence." converting a list of ndarray into a ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to run following code on Kaggle, which shall read every images inside a directory and return them as an ndarray.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import tensorflow as tf

x = []
y = []
names = os.listdir("/kaggle/input/bacteria-detection-with-darkfield-microscopy/images")
for name in names:
    image_path = f"/kaggle/input/bacteria-detection-with-darkfield-microscopy/images/{name}"
    mask_path = f"/kaggle/input/bacteria-detection-with-darkfield-microscopy/masks/{name}"
    assert os.path.exists(image_path)
    assert os.path.exists(mask_path)
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    mask = cv2.imread(mask_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    assert len(image.shape) == 3
    assert len(mask.shape) == 2
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = image / 255.
    x.append(image)
    y.append(mask)
x = np.array(x).astype(np.float32)
y = np.array(y).astype(np.float32)
x.shape, y.shape
```

But I get the following error message, which confuses me:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-f21372cae6bc> in <module>
     15     x.append(image)
     16     y.append(mask)
---> 17 x = np.array(x).astype(np.float32)
     18 y = np.array(y).astype(np.float32)
     19 x.shape, y.shape

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

x and y should be a list of ndarray objects so I don't get why I can not convert them into ndarray objects of a higher dimension.

Comment: Often you can. but `astype` can't do that.  It can't change dimensions.

Comment: Is x empty, what is its shape?

Comment: Before the `astype`, check the `dtype` and `shape` of `x`.  If 1d and object, check the shape of all element arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What most likely happens is that the elements in `x` and `y` are not of same shape. If that is the case, when you append them to a list and use `np.array(x)`(or `np.array(y)`), it cannot create a numpy array since the shape is not rectangular (although this does not throw an error by itself). It just create a list of numpy arrays instead. Hence, when you try to use  `.astype(np.float32)` on a list ( and not a numpy array) it throws the error which states your input is sequence and not an array.

This example shows the difference:

```
np.array([np.array([0,1]), np.array([2,3,4])])

[array([0, 1]) array([2, 3, 4])]
```

vs.

```
np.array([np.array([0,1]), np.array([2,3])])

[[0 1]
 [2 3]]
```

I recommend replacing the corresponding lines in your code with this instead:

```
    x.append(image.astype(np.float32))
    y.append(mask.astype(np.float32))
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)
```

be mindful in this case, `x` and `y` are lists and not a numpy array and the last line will still throw an error. Another solution is try to make all images of the same shape first and use your original code in question.